# Show multiple lines in push notification android Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Im suffering from a problem in notification. Im doing my project in PHONEGAP.
I want to show multiple lines in push notification in android. Now i am only getting single line notification. i cannot expand or do anything with that notification. im using a phonegap plugin.

> com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin

Please help me to overcome this problem.
Screen shot is given below.

**Current Notification** 
[image]

**Expected Notification**
[image]

Comment: Hope this will help : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706818/how-can-i-send-an-apple-push-notification-with-multiple-lines-i-e-with-a-n-c

Answer (score 4):

This involves a custom layout in the native notification (remoteviews) , so it is needed to modify you favorite plugin

[Android custom notification layout with RemoteViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23222063/android-custom-notification-layout-with-remoteviews)

In case of this plugin: https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin

1. Modify GCMIntentService.java, particulary NotificationCompat.Builder setContent with a the custom View. This custom view can be loaded from xml or instatiated by code: [How to create a RelativeLayout programmatically with two buttons one on top of the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979212/programmatically-creating-a-relativelayout-in-android)

Example of a custom builder: [Create custom notification, android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16168553/create-custom-notification-android)

2. Change the params for the plugin or parse payload message to separate lines

Comment: how to modify ? can you be more specific ?
Im using [this](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) plugin. I dont know about modifying the plugin.

Comment: Modify GCMIntentService.java, see answer

Comment: I want to show only the full message in notification. Now its only showing a single line of content and title(refer screenshot). can you please help me do the same with sample code if possible. Because i'm litle behind in android development. So i used phonegap.

Comment: And if you use .Net instead of Java ?

Answer (score 3):

**Path:** \platforms\android\src\com\plugin\gcm

**Filename:** GCMIntentService.java

```
String message = extras.getString("message");
        if (message != null) {
            mBuilder.setContentText(message);
            mBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message));//add this line
```

Comment: This solution has no effect on the style of the push notification. It still appears as one line on Android devices. Do you know what could be the problem? Do I have to clear cache somewhere or rest plugin?